# Select columns of specific types and manipulate their content

Tags: r, dplyr

here it is my problem in the form of a reproducible example and my partial attempt of solution

```
# input
mydf_in<-data.frame(a=letters[6:10], 
                 b=c("<0.5","2","<0.5", "9", "10"), 
                 c=1:5, 
                 d=6:10, 
                 e=c("<0.8","12","<0.8", "<0.8", "<0.8"))

mydf_in

# output 
# the desired final result

mydf_out<-data.frame(a=letters[6:10],
                     b=c(0.5,2,0.5,9,10),
                     b_flag=c(1,0,1,0,0),
                     c=1:5, 
                     d=6:10, 
                     e=c(0.8,12,0.8,0.8,0.8),
                     e_flag=c(1,0,1,1,1)
                     )

mydf_out

library(tidyverse)

mydf_in %>%
  select(where(~ is.character(.x) & 
                 any(str_detect(.x, "<")
                     )
               )
         ) %>%
  
  # in between here is missing the creation and
  # the population of the flagging columns, i.e. "b_flag" and "e_flag"
  
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_replace(.x, "<", ""))))
```

in short, what is missing in the between of the above code snippet, for each selected column:

- create a corresponding flagging column
- populate the rows of the flagging column with 1 or 0 depending on the presence of the sign "<" (see desired output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use the conditions explicitly, instead of `select` use `mutate` with the `where` the condition - to create the 'flag' columns loop over the columns with `across` and to change the column types use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mydf_in %>%
    mutate(across(where(~ is.character(.x) & 
        any(str_detect(.x, fixed("<")))), ~
     +(str_detect(.x, fixed("<"))), .names = "{.col}_flag"), 
   across(where(~ is.character(.x) & 
    any(str_detect(.x, fixed("<")))), ~ readr::parse_number(.)))
```

-output

```
  a    b c  d    e b_flag e_flag
1 f  0.5 1  6  0.8      1      1
2 g  2.0 2  7 12.0      0      0
3 h  0.5 3  8  0.8      1      1
4 i  9.0 4  9  0.8      0      1
5 j 10.0 5 10  0.8      0      1
```

Comment: @maxbre updated the post

Comment: wow, that's great! I need to understand better that bit  `+(str_detect(.x, fixed("<"))), .names = "{.col}_flag")`; I can not really grasp it now, can you please comment it a little? thanks

Comment: @maxbre the `str_detect` returns a logical vector based on the occurrence of character `<`, which is then converted to binary with coersion (`+`) or can also be `as.integer` because `TRUE/FALSE` is otherwise `1/0`.  In the `.names` you can extend the column name by addign a prefix/suffix.  If we don't use `.names`, it will update the original column.  The `.col` represents the original column name for that column looped

Comment: @maxbre that will give the `sum` over the column where all the TRUE/1 are added to give 2 and 4 for the columns 'b' and 'e'

Comment: `+(str_detect(.x, fixed("<")))` is equivalent to `as.integer((str_detect(.x, fixed("<"))))`

Comment: @maxbre both are same.  My option was just to keep the code compact

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl()` to make a logical vector for the flag columns. `as.interger` will give 1s and 0s instead of TRUE and FALSE. Then use `gsub()` to clean up your initial columns.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf_in %>%
mutate(b_flag = grepl("<",mydf_in$b) %>% as.integer,
       e_flag = grepl("<",mydf_in$e) %>% as.integer,
       b = gsub("<","", mydf_in$b),
       e = gsub("<","", mydf_in$b)) %>%
  select(a,b,b_flag,c,d,e_flag) 

   a   b b_flag c  d e_flag
1 f 0.5      1 1  6      1
2 g   2      0 2  7      0
3 h 0.5      1 3  8      1
4 i   9      0 4  9      1
5 j  10      0 5 10      1
```

And if you happen to have several more columns that needed flags, you could use `grepl()` in combination with `lapply()` or `sapply()` like this:

```
#make all flags
flags_columns<-mydf_in[,grepl("<",mydf_in)] %>% sapply(., grepl, pattern = "<") %>%
  data.frame(.) %>%
  sapply(., as.integer) %>% data.frame(.)%>%
  rename_with(., ~paste0(.,"_flag"))

#remove "<" from all columns
edited_columns<- mydf_in[,grepl("<",mydf_in)]  %>% lapply(., gsub, pattern = "<", replacement = "") %>%data.frame(.)

#gather any other columns 
anything_else<- mydf_in[,!grepl("<",mydf_in)] 

#make a dataframe
data.frame(c(flags_columns,edited_columns,anything_else)
```